# Error in UseMethod("type") : no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"

Tags: r, emoji, tm

Trying to run the following code in a Twitter emoji analysis, but I am getting an error and cannot solve it.

```
rank <- emojis_matching(usermedia$text, matchto, description) %>% 
   group_by(description) %>% 
   summarise(n = sum(count)) %>%
   arrange(-n)
```

The error is:

> Error in UseMethod("type") :    no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: check how your usermedia$text has been loaded. You probably loaded it as a factor.